# rational number plane vector space or not?

Tags: vector-spaces, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, real-numbers

Two questions:
1. Is $\mathbb{Q}^2$ a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}$?
2. Is $\mathbb{Q}^2$ a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$?

My answer to the first question is yes. Because the multiplication of rational number 
is rational number. So it is closed under the multiplication.

However, the second one is not. Since it is possible that the multiplication of real number and a rational number is not a rational number, so it will not closed in the multiplication. Remember the vectoe space is $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Is this proof right? or any strict proof?

Thanks

Comment: Your counter example seems right to me.

Comment: (2) Looks good, assuming that the action of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is the normal multiplication of the real numbers. For (1) I would suggest you to show it using the formal definition of a vector space over field $\mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another proof for point $2$: $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable, $\mathbb{R}$ is not, so $\mathbb{Q}^2$ can't be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition that might help you to write out $(1)$ in a formal way.

**Definition:** Let $F$ be a field, *a vector space over $F$* is a set $V$ together with

1. a binary operation $+$ on $V$ under which $V$ is an abelian group,
2. an action of $F$ on $V$ (that is,  a map $F\times V \rightarrow V$) denoted by $rv$, for all $r\in F$ and for all $v\in V$ which satisfies
   $$(r+s)v = rv+sv,\quad \forall r,s\in F,\forall v\in V$$
   $$(rs)v = r(sv),\quad \forall r,s\in F,\forall v\in V$$
   $$r(v+u) = rv+ru,\quad \forall r\in F,\forall v, u\in V$$
   $$1v = v \quad\forall  v \in V.$$